# How I can split list of dict by duplicate value?

Tags: python

I  have some list of dicts with duplicates values, for example:

```
test=[

        {
            'title': 'some_title_1',
            'hash': 3663931876494985241},
        {
            'title': 'some_title_2',
            'hash': -314274274615063890},
        {
            'title': 'some_title_3',
            'hash': 3663931876494985241},
        {
            'title': 'some_title_4',
            'hash': -1845641831329812428
        }
    ]
```

I need split this list on two lists by first duplicate, which I have:

```
fisrt_list=[
    {
        'title': 'some_title_1',
        'hash': 3663931876494985241},
    {
        'title': 'some_title_2',
        'hash': -314274274615063890},
    {
]
second_list=[
    {
        'title': 'some_title_3',
        'hash': 3663931876494985241 # it is duplicate},
    {
        'title': 'some_title_4',
        'hash': -1845641831329812428
    }
]
```

I do it by the next code:

```
flipped = {}
for index, value in enumerate(merged_ads):
    if value['title_and_url_hash'] not in flipped:
        flipped[value['title_and_url_hash']] = [index]
    else:
        flipped[value['title_and_url_hash']].append(index)

for index, value in enumerate(flipped.items()):
    if len(value[1]) > 1:
        fisrt_list.insert(0, test[value[1][0]])
        second_list.insert(0, test[value[1][1]])
    else:
        if not index and len(value[1]) > 1:
            second_list.insert(0, test[value[1][1]]
    )
    if index and len(value[1]) > 1:
        second_list.append(test[value[1][1]])
    else:
        fisrt_list.append(test[value[1][0]])
```

But my code is very dirty.

How can I make it cleaner and better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my probably cleaner version. The result of function `split_by_dup(...)` is a list of lists, so for you example it returns a list `[first_list, second_list]` (see Output down below for clarification).

Also my code supports any amount of splits, not just into two lists but also any amount of sub-lists.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZLfasMgFMbvfYpzZwJZiX9iTWB7kRJCRgwNWCNqL8rYs2fR0mYdvdhgB73wfJ@/7yDaSzjOhi3LoEbwVk@he790w9lm2oe8QbCWK0AX4OEVDm2Rtlchy5M2zg4UTAZW@9UdaxpBHfCx90fcRtFvUgLuemuVGTKdP/S/pWwJsfyuH4bsjtwEfSOpa28N1sqsXHiDcgv9GehUODsDDqGgfIiRqf1xv4DDFLTCDWA/n1SXTh3BxWZIkzTAhGA1I3IveM1rWVFOkuez@A2RPiG@MMLpPi5BqlIwWZd/ILJ/n5E/m5FIXglOJCOM1pJQTuUN2SJk3WRC9vCb4jvnOVqWLw)

```
def split_by_dup(lst):
    r, l, s = [], [], set()
    for e in lst:
        if e['hash'] in s:
            r.append(l)
            l, s = [], set()
        s.add(e['hash'])
        l.append(e)
    if len(l) > 0:
        r.append(l)
    return r

test = [
    {
        'title': 'some_title_1',
        'hash': 3663931876494985241
    },
    {
        'title': 'some_title_2',
        'hash': -314274274615063890
    },
    {
        'title': 'some_title_3',
        'hash': 3663931876494985241
    },
    {
        'title': 'some_title_4',
        'hash': -1845641831329812428
    },
]

print(split_by_dup(test))
```

Output:

```
[
    [
        {'title': 'some_title_1', 'hash': 3663931876494985241},
        {'title': 'some_title_2', 'hash': -314274274615063890}
    ],

    [
        {'title': 'some_title_3', 'hash': 3663931876494985241},
        {'title': 'some_title_4', 'hash': -1845641831329812428}
    ]
]
```

---

If the task is to split into exactly two sub-lists (not any amount of sub-lists) then function above can be simplified much more:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZHNaoQwFEb3eYq7i4IdJj9motAnERGLVww4Kua6GEqf3WpgnCnMooV@ZJFLTg4fyXSjbhzUujbYgp96R9XHrWqWKeo9xTmDLR7ewSNFcZjacQaXAIIbAIflinNN@ETvcS1gwbvad7zcOf842jMjLfMA250id2USNi4vD8af6qaJDkPMGKGnrUURkM8D5OSoR54D9@MVqzBVgicPIBhyUMaoTAl7MTrTmU2lFoH5Sn5jlC@Mb0poedmXEenZKJud/2BU/95Rv@oorE6NFlYJJTMrpJb2riwZm2Y3UPTj0/d3jmO2rt8)

```
def split_by_dup(lst):
    s = set()
    for i, e in enumerate(lst):
        if e['hash'] in s:
            return lst[:i], lst[i:]
        s.add(e['hash'])
```

Comment: Test it on real data. Really nice solution. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler version.

```
temp = []
for i in enumerate(merged_list):
    if i[1]['hash'] not in temp:
        temp.append(i[1]['hash'])
    else:
        first_list = merged_list[:i[0]]
        second_list = merged_list[i[0]:]
        break
print(first_list)
print(second_list)
```

Comment: Just a small notice for possible improvement - for hashable types it is much better to use `set()` instead of list `[]`, because search in a set takes `O(1)` time and in a list `O(N)` time. So searching in a list will be very slow for large inputs, because your algorithm will be of `O(N^2)` complexity.

Comment: I thought of using set at first but then switched to a list for no reason lol! Thanks.